# What could cause a forest of bent trees?

Tags: botany

While hiking on the northern Idaho-Montana border, I encountered a large area where virtually every tree is bent at the base in the downhill direction.  Only the very largest and very smallest trees are straight.  What could cause this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Avalanche?  Or just a heavy accumulation of snow bending them towards the ground one year.  I could find you some hereabouts that are bent into U-shapes, or even S-curves.

Comment: Forgot to remove the fisheye lens?

Comment: This case is much different, but you might find it relevant: [Crooked Forrest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crooked_Forest).

Comment: A forest near my grandparents farm has a bunch of bent trees due to a tornado 40 years ago. That being said, if they are all bent at such a similar angle geotropism seems more likely.

Comment: Prevailing winds, you see a lot on the coast.

Comment: Also see,the Dancing Forest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Forest they think it might have been caterpillars.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The phenomenon in question is probably related to [geotropism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitropism).

If the hill soil is "on the move" it will cause the bend on the trees -

> If the soil in a slope is moving downward, the trees on this slope
>   will tip downward.  As the tree continues to try to grow upward, the
>   trunk will show a curve. The degree of bending could indicate the rate
>   or amount of movement of the soil.

[image]

[source](http://www.geocaching.com/geocache/GC3T6RQ_beware-of-bent-trees)

Comment: This was a surprisingly interesting question and answer.

Comment: @canadianer :) thanks, nice to help to community %)